# How to identify used device

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, web, server

Is there any better way to identify user device? User viewing from PC or smartphone or an odinary phone. How can we understand that?

Comment: A better way than what? Why do you need to identify device? Please, don't repeat title in body question, use a more relevant title instead

Comment: *"...or an odinary phone..."* Oh wow, I **am** getting old, if phones with internet access are "ordinary," not even "smart".

Comment: how can i understand the user device. thats the only question

Comment: `how can i understand the user device`  Understand device???

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : i mean android/ios like phones smartphones

Comment: @A.Wolff : check user is coming form PC/Smart-phone/ordinatory phone

Comment: @murshid_Dev You can use browser user-agent but that's just calling for problem. Better is to use feature detection instead. That's why i asked you why you would need that, an other approach would be better i guess

Comment: @murshid_Dev: https://github.com/matthewhudson/DEVICE.js  you have everything here for most of known user agents, and if support for this library drops you can update yourself (client side).

Answer (score 0):

The way this is done is through the [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header in the HTTP request. The actual user-agent string isn't standardized and anyone can forge it to be whatever they want, so you kind of have to take that into account.

Here's a list of common "mobile" user-agent strings: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/

Comment: BTW, we cannot predict what will be the user-agent of, e.g, iPhone 7. I meant, can be really hard to maintain

Comment: of course not. But by definition this is what the user-agent is for. To declare what kind of client is submitting the request

Answer (score 0):

After reading the conversation I guess
this code might help you:

```
alert(navigator.userAgent)
```

It will give you the details of users device.
you can also use it in the following manner:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```